# How can I change the name that shows up on Google Calendar Invites?

Tags: google-calendar, account-management, google-workspace-for-business

When I send a calendar invite, my name shows up as "david". I'd like to change to my proper name. I haven't found a way to change it. I obviously want to change it for all the invites I send. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- **either here: https://aboutme.google.com/u/0/#name**

  [image: 1]
- **or directly in [Contacts](https://contacts.google.com/other?hl=en-GB) (if you sending it to yourself from another account)**

  [image: 5]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when using a google workspace. Creating a currents profile solved this for me. Log in to workspace and set up the profile at this link - https://currents.google.com

Answer (score 0):

creating a google currents profile solved the issue for me

Comment: This sounds stupid but that's fact :D